# Put post urls into their own category

Tags: blog

I'm trying to update a blog post url to have its own parent. For example I want to change this url from:

test.com/blog/my-post

to

test.com/blog/category/my-post

When updating in the edit post page, it reverts back to the original. Do I need a custom post type or something? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can't add subfolders on individual posts. You can go to Settings > Permalinks and set it up there - you'll want to use a custom structure:

`/blog/%category%/%postname%/`